# Testing facebook login on django development server

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I am trying to integrate facebook login in my django app but everytime I click on facebook login button it gives me an error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I my app settings my site url is

> ```
> http://localhost:8000/
> ```

and also in my hosts file localhost have been mapped to 127.0.0.1
how to solve this as I have followed similar questions on stack but none helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your host file, set the localhost:port to the domain you wish to log in from.

Then, set the Facebook app's domain to the domain you've pointed your localhost to.